# Installing SSL with Certbot on RTMP enabled Nginx Server in Ubuntu

Tags: nginx, ssl, ubuntu-18.04, certbot, rtmp

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 OS. I installed rtmp-module for nginx v18.01 and send streams on it. I can access to server with IP and domain name. Indeed I need SSL on this server. But when I install SSL with CertBot on the server, all the settings of the previous Nginx server are deleted and the web server version drops to 14. How can I install SSL on the server and the previous settings remain intact?

Answer (score 1):

CertBot provides an automatic way to handle Nginx configurations. This accomplishes most common and generic Nginx setups.

If this doesn't match your expectations than you can use CertBot to issue certificates manually:

```
certbot certonly --manual ...
```